# Adding a relationship leads to an error in Graph Data Science Library

Tags: python, neo4j, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-browser, graph-data-science

I have imported 500k Nodes and 1M relationships in the DB (
Version 4.2.1) of Neo4j (1.4.7) without any problems.

Furthermore I have installed the plugins APOC (4.2.0.0) and Graph Data Science Library (1.4.1) without any errors.

I'm able to inspect all nodes and relationships in the Neo4j Browser, but when I try to use the GDSL an error occurs and I have to add following line into my neo4j.conf:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=,jwt.security.*,gds.*,apoc.*
```

I added the line into the config, but error still occurring.

So I tried to figure out, when the error occurs.

- When I add all nodes into my DB the GDSL is working fine.
- When I add my relationships step by step then the error only appears, after I added a specific relationship.

When I skip this relationship then it is working in Neo4j Browser and GDSL. But when I add this relationship its only working in Neo4j Browser.

The relationships looks like this:

```
match(p:packages)
with p
match(c:commits)
where p.projectid = c.projectid
create(p)-[:commits]->(c)
```

Nothing special.

My Commit Nodes:

```
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------     --------------  -----
 0   projectid  25622 non-null  int64
 1   counts     25622 non-null  int64
 2   counts2    25622 non-null  int64
dtypes: int64(3)
```

My Packages nodes looking like this:

```
     #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------       --------------  ----- 
 0   packagename  26023 non-null  object
 1   versions     26023 non-null  int64 
 2   projectid    26023 non-null  int64 
 3   ownerid      26023 non-null  int64 
 4   projectname  26023 non-null  object
 5   language     26023 non-null  object
```

Im not looking for specifics solution, but I have no Ideas anymore what could be the error.

Already tried different versions. Different imports and so on ...

Any one else have a idea why a specific relationship is only working in Neo4j Browser and not in GDSL?

Thanks

Comment: What is not working with the GDSL?

Comment: Im not able to open the playground anymore. It shows that I have to add the dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted line. But I already did it.

Comment: Can you add a small version of the data to reproduce the error on https://github.com/neo4j-devtools/neuler

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the name of the relationship was already used for a node.
I changed the name for the relationship and now it works.

Seems that GDSL also needs different labels for the nodes and relationships.

Comment: It seems that this is more of an exception, I've tried to reproduce this on a small graph but was unable...

Comment: for me it was the solution. Also check out the code (https://pastebin.com/GNxKQUBH)